# Is the KTS lithium battery for my motherboard broken, or is it something else?

Tags: motherboard, battery, power

For the past few months, I have been having some problems with my PC that involve it not powering on when everything is connected as it should be, e.g. power cable plugged in, power supply switched on and plugged into motherboard as it should be. 
When working, the power light on my graphics card lights up, and then I would be able to simply press the power button on the PC as you do, and it would power on.
But every now and then, when I go to my PC, the power light on my graphics card isn't on and the PC won't switch on, regardless of whether or not the power supply is on or off.
I looked it up on Google a while back and found an answer that fixed this, remove the small coin shaped battery labeled KTS on the motherboard for about 30 secs and make sure there aren't any scratches on it,  then put it back in and it should be working fine... Which it has been until recently.
Now when I do this, nothing changes and it still won't switch on. Have I simply worn out the battery by removing it too many times or is it the whole motherboard or what?

Comment: How old is the motherboard? You can usually expect the CMOS battery to last at least five years. A replacement CR2032 battery should not be expensive, maybe 2USD at most for a reputable brand such as Panasonic, Energizer or Duracell.

Comment: Not quite sure how old, I bought it as a prebuilt system back in mid 2015, the motherboard is a GIGABYTE GA-F2A78M-HD2 if that helps in any way

Comment: That's quite a recent motherboard but it is possible that the battery ran down unexpectedly early. Removing the battery for a little while has the effect of resetting the BIOS - it should have no effect on the life of the battery. Can you contact the system builder and find out if they have any suggestions? If they build a few with the same specs then they might be aware of some issue.

Comment: If the BOIS is reset multiple times over 2 or 3 months (roughly once a week, that's how often I had to do this in the past) is there a chance that the BIOS would get corrupted? I've been told that's a possibility under my circumstances

Comment: As you now have a non-booting system, I'd say replace the battery. If the original one was dying/dead then the BIOS *settings* could become corrupt while the PC is switched off and lead to an unbootable system.